# How could I type check CGColor / CGPath?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, core-animation, core-foundation

So what it appears there is a [filed bug for swift](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-1612) relating to the CoreFoundation types. Based on the description it appears there is not type checking for CGPath and CGColor, below is a snippet from the bug that demonstrates the behavior.

```
func check(a: AnyObject) -> Bool {
    return a is CGColor
}

check("hey") --> true
check(1.0) --> true
check(UIColor.redColor()) --> true
```

And here is what I'm trying to do

```
if let value = self.valueForKeyPath(keyPath) {
    if let currentValue = value as? CGColor {
        // Do Something with CGColor
    } else if let currentValue = value as? CGSize {
        // Do Something with CGSize
    } else  if let currentValue = value as? CGPoint {
        // Do Something with CGPoint
    }
}
```

I've done the following, by type checking type the types I know work first, then tagging on the last statement for AnyObject, and checking the CFTypeID. This works for now, but [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFTypeRef/#//apple_ref/c/tdef/CFTypeID) says that the the CFTypeID can change, and should not be relied upon.

```
    if let currentValue = value as? CGPoint {
        // Do Something with CGPoint
    } else if let currentValue = value as? CGSize {
        // Do Something with CGSize
    } else if let currentValue = value as? AnyObject {
         if CFGetTypeID(currentValue) == 269 {
              // Cast and do Something with CGColor  
              methodCall((currentValue as! CGColor))
         }
   }
```

Has anyone found a reliable workaround a for this issue? As I do not want to use this hack as a long term solution

Comment: I am not familiar with this problem, but instead of comparing against the hard-coded constant `269` you could compare against `CGColorGetTypeID()`.

Comment: @MartinR amazing that's exactly what I was looking for!! I didn't want to hard code that value in case it changed :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Apple writes:](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corefoundation/cftypeid)

> Because the value for a type ID can change from release to release, your code should not rely on stored or hard-coded type IDs nor should it hard-code any observed properties of a type ID (such as, for example, it being a small integer).

That means that you should obtain the type ID at *runtime*, in your case:

```
if CFGetTypeID(currentValue) == CGColorGetTypeID() { ... }
```